# Props not passing to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The props aren't getting passed to the child component. It is showing an empty object when printed. The issue is in the `News.js` file. All other functionalities are working except the passage of props.
The props are passed in `App.js` to `News.js`. Issue is with passing props to the child component.

`App.js`:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Axios from'axios';
import {v4 as uuidv4} from "uuid"; 
import './App.css';
import News from './components/News';

const App = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

    const APP_KEY = "hidden due to privacy issues";
    // const content = "kerala";
    const url =  `https://gnews.io/api/v3/search?q=${query}&token=${APP_KEY}`;
    // GET https://gnews.io/api/v3/search?q=example&token=API-Token 

    const getData = async () => {
        const result = await Axios.get(url)
        .then(result=>{
            console.log('inside getdata');
            
            setNews(result.data.articles);
            console.log(result);
            setQuery(" ");
            
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        
        
    };

    const onChange = e => {
        setQuery(e.target.value);
        
    };

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        getData();
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
             <h1>NEWSPAPER</h1>  
           </header> 
           <form className="search-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                 <input 
                 type="text"
                 placeholder="Search News!" 
                 onChange={onChange}
                 value={query}
                 />
                 <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
            </form>
            <div className="news">
                {news !== [] && news.map(newsItem =>
                    <News key={uuidv4()} props={newsItem}/> 
                    // console.log(newsItem)
                    
                    )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

The props are passed in `App.js` to `News.js`. Issue is with passing props to the child component.

Comment: Read the last three lines, what do you think Facebook is doing?

Comment: Note: `news !== []` will **always** be true. `[] !== []` is true, no two objects are equal to each other. This isn't likely to be the problem you're asking about, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you’re passing it as `props = newsItem`, you’ll get this in the child component with `props.props.newsItem`

Comment: @ Rahul - Good eye!!

Answer (score 2):

You're creating `News` with no props at the very end of `News.js`:

```
export default function Facebook() {
  return <News />  // <=========================== here
}
```

That's why you're seeing a `News` component created without any props.

See also [Rahul Dwivedi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62147131/157247), you probably want `newsItem={newsItem}`, not `props={newsItem}`.

---

A side note regarding:

```
<div className="news">
    {news !== [] && news.map(newsItem =>
        <News key={uuidv4()} props={newsItem}/> 
        // console.log(newsItem)

        )}
</div>
```

`news !== []` is **always** true. No two objects are ever equal to each other. If you wanted a guard there to prevent teh call to `map` when `news` is empty, you'd use `news.length !== 0`:

```
<div className="news">
    {news.length !== 0 && news.map(newsItem =>
        <News key={uuidv4()} props={newsItem}/> 
    )}
</div>
```

**but** you don't need one; calling `map` on an empty array is harmless, it produces an empty array:

```
<div className="news">
    {news.map(newsItem =>
        <News key={uuidv4()} props={newsItem}/> 
    )}
</div>
```